# Laptop monitor doesn't seem to be detected right

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution, monitor

I am using Ubuntu MATE on an ASUS ZX53VW laptop with a 960m graphics card. I've installed the proprietary NVIDIA driver version 387.34.

When I open NVIDIA X Server Settings I get a popup:

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.
Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root),
and restart the X server.
```

I run nvidia-xconfig as mentioned and get the following result:

```
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

However when I restart lightdm (or reboot) and try to open NVIDIA X Server Settings again, I get the same problem. The xorg.conf looks like this:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 387.34  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-15)  Tue Nov 21 03:31:45 PST 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection


Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Unknown"
HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

It looks like it was unable to identify the monitor. Indeed if I run sudo get-edid | parse-edid, I get:

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!
Attempting to use the classical VBE interface

Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
```

Then it just hangs there. I guess it looks like the monitor isn't identifying itself via EDID.

The consequence of this problem is that I'm stuck on 800x600 resolution. Any ideas for how to fix this?